# PrettyPhoto with custom gallery images using API

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a large image and a set of smaller thumbs. When you click one of the smaller thumbs, the big image is replaced with corresponding image the user clicked on.

When you click the large image, a prettybox lightbox pops up.

I'm trying to make it so that prettybox will open up as a gallery using the images from the thumbs as the gallery images.

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    api_images = [];
    $('#gallery-thumbs li').each(function(index, element){
        var largeImage = $(element).attr('data-large');// I'm storing the large version of each thumbnail in this HTML property
        api_images.push(largeImage);
    });
    $.prettyPhoto.open(api_images);// This is the line with the error
});
```

I'm getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

Thank you

Comment: Deleted my answer because I hadn't read far enough in the prettyPhoto API.  What you are doing above is correct according to that.  Have you looked to see if it's 'prettyPhoto' or 'open' that is the undefined part?  Are you using the correct version (minimum of 2.5).

Comment: I'm using the latest version v.3.1.5. When I console.log($.prettyPhoto) before setting $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();, I get an object with 1 property (version: "3.1.5"). None of the methods are available until I put in $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a bit of a hack, but it works. I created a hidden element

```
<a rel="target" href="/cms_images/gallery/foose-legend-55-bel-air.jpg" style="display:none">
    <img src="/cms_images/random.jpg" alt=" />
</a>
```

Then when the user clicks the real image, I initiate prettyPhoto using the hidden element

```
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var indexBig = $(this).attr('data-index');
        api_images = [];
        // Initiate prettyPhoto by passing it a hidden target
        $("a[rel^='target']").prettyPhoto();
        $('#gallery-thumbs li').each(function(index, element){
            var largeImage = $(element).find('a').attr('data-large');
            api_images.push(largeImage);
        });
        $.prettyPhoto.open(api_images);
        $.prettyPhoto.changePage(indexBig - 1);
        // Undo prettyPhoto so it can be reused
        $("a[rel^='target']").unbind('click');
        return false;
    });
```